# AttributeError: module 'urllib3' has no attribute 'urlopen' in python

Tags: python, urllib, urllib3

I am trying to send temperature data over onto one of my website currently online. This code consists of measuring the temperature through a sensor(ds18b20), sending that data onto a mysql databse entitled temp_pi and specifically onto a table intitled TAB_CLASSROOM and lastly sending that data onto a webpage of mine. Everything in this code runs except for the `sendDataToServer()` part. I specify the error right before this particular line. I have the PHP set up on my website for this to work.

```
import os
import glob
import time
import MySQLdb
import datetime
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error

#define db and cur

db = MySQLdb.connect(host = "127.0.0.1", user = "root", passwd = "xB7O4fXmuMpF6M0u", db = "temp_pi")
cur = db.cursor()

#connection to the database
try:
    connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='127.0.0.1',
                             database='temp_pi',
                             user='root',
                             password='xB7O4fXmuMpF6M0u')

    if connection.is_connected():
       db_Info = connection.get_server_info()
       print("Connected to MySQL database... MySQL Server version on ",db_Info)
       cursor = connection.cursor()
       cursor.execute("select database();")
       record = cursor.fetchone()
       print ("Your connected to - ", record)

except Error as e :
    print ("Error while connecting to MySQL", e)

#obtaining the temperature through the ds18b20 sensor            
os.system('modprobe w1-gpio')
os.system('modprobe w1-therm')

base_dir = '/sys/bus/w1/devices/'
device_folder = glob.glob(base_dir + '28*')[0]
device_file = device_folder + '/w1_slave'

def read_temp_raw():
    f = open(device_file, 'r')
    lines = f.readlines()
    f.close()
    return lines

def read_temp():
    lines = read_temp_raw()
    while lines[0].strip()[-3:] != 'YES':
        time.sleep(0.2)
        lines = read_temp_raw()
    equals_pos = lines[1].find('t=')
    if equals_pos != -1:
        temp_string = lines[1][equals_pos+2:]
        temp_c = float(temp_string) / 1000.0
        temp_f = temp_c * 9.0 / 5.0 + 32.0
        return temp_c  
#Defining sendDataToServer() and trying to send this data towards my website
def sendDataToServer():
    global temperature

    threading.Timer(600,sendDataToServer).start()
    print("Mesuring...")
    read_temp()
    temperature = read_temp()
    print(temperature)
    temp= read_temp()
    urllib3.urlopen("http://francoouesttemp.tech/weather/add_data.php?temp="+temp).read()
#insertion of data into the mysql database
while True:
        print("putting temperature data into temp_pi database")
        i = datetime.datetime.now()
        year = str(i.year)
        month = str(i.month)
        day = str(i.day)
        date = day + "-" + month + "-" + year

        hour = str(i.hour)
        minute = str(i.minute)
        second = str(i.second)
        timestr = hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second

        valT = str(read_temp())

        try:
            cur.execute("""INSERT INTO TAB_CLASSROOM(temp_c,T_Date,T_Time) VALUES(%s,%s,%s)""",(valT,i,timestr))
            db.commit()
        except:
            db.rollback()

        time.sleep(5)

        #this is the part where my code tells me : NameError : name 'urllib3' is not defined ----- I want this part of the code to send the temperature, date and time over to my website.     
        sendDataToServer()

cur.close()  
db.close()
```

Comment: the same problem look my solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63734222/solved-what-should-i-use-to-open-a-url-instead-of-urlopen-in-urllib3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to send requests using `urllib3`, you need to [create a pool manager](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html#making-requests) first.

Alternatively, you could use the HTTP client in the Python standard library.  Its `urlopen` function is called [`urllib.request.urlopen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlopen). Depending on what you are trying to do, the [`requests` package](http://docs.python-requests.org/) might also be an option, but it has certain disadvantages when it comes to certificate management for HTTPS URLs (the built-in client will automatically use the system certificate store).

Comment: `AttributeError: module 'urllib3.request' has no attribute 'urlopen'` this is the error I am now getting with the updated code u have suggested.

Comment: `urllib.request.urlopen`, different top-level module.

Comment: when I do put that, it just gives this following error : `NameError : name 'urllib' is not defined`

Comment: Sorry, you need to import it (`import urllib.request`).

Comment: Ok that changed the error so now it might be an error to have to do with PHP. But i am unsure. Here is the error :  `TypeError: Can't convert 'float' object to str implicitly`

Comment: You also need to add to change `+ temp` into `+ str(temp)`, I assume, or use some other way to construct the request string.

Comment: Ok that got the code to run. But the data is not showing up onto my website... What does the `str(temp)` do? Because that could maybe have affected the PHP variables in my php code.

Comment: It converts the floating point value (such as `21.2`) into a string (`'21.2'`).

Comment: Alright. So it has to be something to do with my PHP code?

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea.

Comment: Alright, well you made my python code work which was indeed my question lol. I have solved one part, the python. XD

Answer (score 4):

```
import urllib 
import requests
url = '....'
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
```

Comment: where exactly would I put the `url = '...'`

Comment: url is argument of the function: response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)